# How to assign a values to a double pointer array which is member of struct in c when it is passed to other function

Tags: c, pointers, struct

I am trying to write a function in  which assigns value to double pointer inside a structure?
struct:

```
typedef struct A{
   int a;
   double **array;
}A;
```

function:

```
int funct_to_write(A* structure){
   double* data;
   data = (double*)malloc(5*sizeof(double));
   for (int i=0; i<5;i++){
       data[i] = i/5;
   }
   structure->(*array) = *data;
   free(data);
return 0;
}
```

But it return an array like undefined actions to a struct pointer. Can some one help me with this?

Prototype:

```
#include <stdlib.h>


typedef struct A{
   int a;
   double **array;
}A;

int funct_to_write(A* structure){
   double* data;
   data = (double*)malloc(5*sizeof(double));
   for (int i=0; i<5;i++){
       data[i] = i/5;
   }
   structure->(*array) = *data;
   free(data);
return 0;
}


int main(){

A structure;
double* original;
int retval = funct_to_write(&structure);
*original = A.(*array);
return 0;

}
```

Comment: Show us the block of code where you are calling `funct_to_write()`.

Comment: `structure->(*array)` is invalid C syntax, did you mean `*(structure->array)`?

Comment: There is too much bad code for me to work out what you are trying to do.

Comment: @IanAbbott Trying to change the value of array inside the struct and assign it to other array.

Comment: Where do you allocate memory for the array inside the struct? The only place where you allocate any memory is in `funct_to_write`, but that only allocates temporary memory that is freed in the same function.

Comment: I didnt allocate as i thought pointing the address of array inside the struct to the starting address of array "data" will be enough . @IanAbbott

Comment: The `double**` seems needlessly complicated. A plain `double*` 1D array seems to be what you want. Also consider using a _flexible array member_ instead of a pointer.